# Why to use DialogFragment?

Tags: android, dialog, android-widget

Basically Dialogs inactivates the activity at the background. So the `DialogFragment` does the same with increased complexity. So why should one go for `DialogFragment` though various subclasses of `Dialog` are available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Fragments` are used with in your activity, but to present a fragment as dialog (window) using `FragmentTransaction` and followup with fragment's life-cycle, you need to use `DialogFragment`. However, you may do use simple `Dialog` too, but then it has nothing to do with the fragment's life-cycle.

As per google docs:

> A DialogFragment can still optionally be used as a normal fragment, if
>   desired. This is useful if you have a fragment that in some cases
>   should be shown as a dialog and others embedded in a larger UI.

Answer (score 4):

FragmentDialog is a fragment that can be:

1. used as fragment, e.g.:

   ```
   FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   trans.add(R.id.navigation_fragment, mFriendFragment);
   trans.commit();
   ```
2. used as dialog, e.g.:

   ```
   FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
   UnsubscribeTabletFragment fragment = new UnsubscribeTabletFragment();
   fragment.show(fm, "dialog");
   ```

So, if you have a fragment, and the fragment sometimes works as fragment, sometimes works as dialog, then you should use this one.

Answer (score 3):

DialogFragment permits to reuse so part of dialog on your app. Just like fragments do it for your layouts.

Here you have a good article about DialogFragment:
http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Answer (score 1):

when u have a dynamic layout in your android app using fragment already, then u need to use it with/in your dialog from an action button click or other click, so this time dialogFragment is more convenient then the normal dialog.